# constexpr function which is shared in multiple modules

Tags: c++, translation-unit, constexpr-function

I noticed a strange behavior when I was working with a constexpr function.
I reduced the code to a simplified example.
Two functions are called from two different translation units (module A and B).

```
#include <iostream>

int mod_a();
int mod_b();

int main()
{
    std::cout << "mod_a(): " << mod_a() << "\n";
    std::cout << "mod_b(): " << mod_b() << "\n";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The modules look similar. This is mod_a.cpp:

```
constexpr int X = 3;
constexpr int Y = 4;

#include "common.h"

int mod_a()
{
    return get_product();
}
```

Only some internal constants differ. This is mod_b.cpp:

```
constexpr int X = 6;
constexpr int Y = 7;

#include "common.h"

int mod_b()
{
    return get_product();
}
```

Both modules use a common `constexpr` function which is defined in "common.h":

```
/* static */ constexpr int get_product()
{
    return X * Y;
}
```

I was very astonished that both functions return 12. Due to the `#include` directive (which should only be some source code inclusion), I supposed that there is no interaction between both modules.
When I defined `get_product` also to be `static`, the behavior was as expected:
`mod_a()` returned 12,
`mod_b()` returned 42.

I also looked Jason Turner's episode 312 of C++ Weekly: Stop Using 'constexpr' (And Use This Instead!) at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pKtPWcl1Go.

The advice to use generally `static constexpr` is a good hint.

But I still wonder if the behavior which I noticed without the `static` keyword is well defined. Or is it UB? Or is it a compiler bug?

Instead of the `constexpr` function I also tried a C-style macro `#define get_product() (X*Y)` which showed me also the expected results (12 and 42).

Take care

michaeL

Comment: basically it's a inline variable/function with different definition, which is UB afaict.

Answer (score 5):

This program ill-formed: `X` and `Y` have internal linkage since they are `const` variables at namespace scope. This means that both definitions of `constexpr int get_product()` (which is implicitly `inline`) violate the [one definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule):

> There can be more than one definition in a program of each of the following: [...], inline function, [...], as long as all the following is true:
>
> - [...]
> - name lookup from within each definition finds the same entities (after overload-resolution), except that
>
>   - constants with internal or no linkage may refer to different objects as long as they are not odr-used and have the same values in every definition

And obviously these constants have different values.

---

What's happening is both `mod_a` and `mod_b` are calling `get_product` at runtime. `get_product` is implicitly inline, so one of the definitions is chosen and the other is discarded. What gcc seems to do is take the first definition found:

```sh
$ g++ mod_a.cpp mod_b.cpp main.cpp && ./a.out
mod_a(): 12
mod_b(): 12
$ g++ mod_b.cpp mod_a.cpp main.cpp && ./a.out
mod_a(): 42
mod_b(): 42
$ g++ -c mod_a.cpp
$ g++ -c mod_b.cpp
$ g++ mod_a.o mod_b.o main.cpp && ./a.out
mod_a(): 12
mod_b(): 12
$ g++ mod_b.o mod_a.o main.cpp && ./a.out
mod_a(): 42
mod_b(): 42
```

It's as if `get_product` isn't `constexpr`, since it is getting called at runtime.

But if you were to enable optimisations (or force `get_product()` to be called at compile time, like with `constexpr int result = get_product(); return result;`), the results are as you would "expect":

```cpp
$ g++ -O1 mod_a.cpp mod_b.cpp main.cpp && ./a.out
mod_a(): 12
mod_b(): 42
```

(Though this is still UB, and the correct fix is to make the functions `static`)

Comment: Thank you very much for your investigations, your good explanations and the hint to the One Definition Rule (ODR). I think I learned a lot of constexpr and linkage.

Answer (score 2):

This code violates the One Definition Rule (language lawyers please correct me if I'm wrong).

If I compile the code separately, I get the behavior that you expect:

```
g++ -O1 -c main.cpp
g++ -O1 -c mod_a.cpp
g++ -O1 -c mod_b.cpp
g++ *.o
./a.out
> mod_a(): 12
> mod_b(): 42
```

If I compile all at once or activate link-time optimization, the UB becomes apparent.

```
g++ -O1 *.cpp
./a.out
> mod_a(): 12
> mod_b(): 12
```

### How to fix this

You are on the right track with declaring them static. More C++-esce would be an anonymous namespace. You should also declare the constants static or put them in a namespace, not just the function.

mod_a.cpp:

```
namespace {
constexpr int X = 3;
constexpr int Y = 4;
}

#include "common.h"

int mod_a()
{
    return get_product();
}
```

common.h:

```
namespace {
constexpr int get_product()
{
    return X * Y;
}
} /* namespace anonymous */
```

Even better, in my opinion: Include the common.h within an opened namespace. That makes the connection between the declarations more apparent and would allow you to have multiple public get_products, one per namespace. Something like this:

mod_a.cpp:

```
namespace {
constexpr int X = 3;
constexpr int Y = 4;

#include "common.h"
} /* namespace anonymous */

int mod_a()
{
    return get_product();
}
```

Comment: Yes, the single namespace make it work like expected. Good idea.
Actually, I noticed this behavior when I wrote some experimental code by abbreviating some work. The include file common.h depends on the constexpr definition which is not nice. For a reasonable application I would provide the constants by a parameter to the function.