# Using constexpr and string_view in module

Tags: c++, linker-errors, constexpr, string-view, c++-modules

Modern C++ offers `constexpr` and `std::string_view` as a convenient alternative to string literals. However, I am unable to link to a "`constexpr std::string_view`" within a module. By contrast, I am able to use `string_view` (*not* `constexpr`) within the module as well as a "`constexpr std::string_view`" *outside* of the module. Furthermore, the problem does not occur for other uses of `constexpr` within the module, such as for integers.

Below is the minimal code to recreate the error:

module interface unit (my_string.cpp):

```
export module my_string;

import <string_view>;

export namespace my_string {
struct MyString {
    static std::string_view string_at_runtime;
    static constexpr std::string_view string_at_compilation{"Hello World at compilation (inside module)"};
    static constexpr int number_at_compilation{1};
};
}
```

module implementation unit (my_string_impl.cpp):

```
module;

module my_string;

namespace my_string {
    std::string_view MyString::string_at_runtime = "Hello World at runtime";
}
```

hello_world.cpp:

```
import <iostream>;
import <string_view>;

import my_string;

static constexpr std::string_view hello_world{"Hello World at compilation (outside module)"};

int main(){
    std::cout << hello_world << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_string::MyString::string_at_runtime << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_string::MyString::number_at_compilation << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_string::MyString::string_at_compilation << std::endl; //<-- ERROR is here
}
```

Compilation and attempt to link (using gcc 11.2.0 running on Linux):

```
g++ -c -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -xc++-system-header iostream  string_view 
g++ -c my_string.cpp -fmodules-ts -std=c++20
g++ -c my_string_impl.cpp -fmodules-ts -std=c++20
g++ -c hello_world.cpp -fmodules-ts -std=c++20
g++ -o main my_string.o my_string_impl.o hello_world.o -fmodules-ts -std=c++20
```

Only the last instruction (linking) results in an error:

```
g++ -o main my_string.o my_string_impl.o hello_world.o -fmodules-ts -std=c++20
/usr/bin/ld: hello_world.o: in function `main':
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x97): undefined reference to `my_string::MyString::string_at_compilation'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In addition to searching the answers to related questions (e.g. [`constexpr` in modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71307601/constexpr-function-which-is-shared-in-multiple-modules) and [`constexpr` and `namespace`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71491141/c20-module-with-namespace))  I have reread the [GCC Wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-modules). I have not yet tried this code with other compilers (e.g. clang, msvc).
Is this error a failure in my code or a not-yet-implemented feature in gcc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a work around solution: adding a getter method.

In the module interface unit (my_string.cpp) add:

```
static std::string_view GetStringAtCompilation();
```

In the module implementation unit (my_string_impl.cpp) add:

```
std::string_view MyString::GetStringAtCompilation(){
    return string_at_compilation;
}
```

And now the following line in the "main" function (see hello_world.cpp in question) compiles, links and executes without error:

```
std::cout << my_string::MyString::GetStringAtCompilation() << std::endl;
```

I believe that the reasons that the original attempt did not work without a getter method is given in this answer about [`constexpr` and `string_view` in headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666043/c-standard-odr-and-constexpr-stdstring-view/45666276#45666276)